# Display elements which starts on first letter Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuex

I want to display only elements which starts on letter thtt i click in my

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <div class="d-flex px-2 pt-5 flex-wrap justify-center">
            <router-link
                class="mx-1 router-text"
                :to="{ name: 'byLetter', params: { letter } }"
                v-for="letter in letters"
                :key="letter">
                {{ letter }}
            </router-link>
        </div>
        <div>
            <v-row>
                <v-col v-for="beer in beers" :key="beer.id" cols="6">
                <v-card class="d-flex flex-column justify-space-between"height="200">
                        <h2 class="ml-3 mt-3">
                            {{ beer.name }}
                            <v-avatar>
                            <v-img :src="beer.image_url" alt="John"></v-img>
                            </v-avatar>
                    </h2>
                <div class="px-5 d-flex text-center align-center justify-space-between">
                    <p>Volume: {{ beer.abv }}%</p>
                <p class="px-7 food">Food pairing: <br />{{ beer.food_pairing }}</p>
                <router-link class="router" :to="{ name: 'details', params: beer }">
                                <v-btn outlined>
                                    <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
                                    Szczegóły
                                </v-btn>
                            </router-link>
                        </div>
                    </v-card>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </div>
    </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    // Imports

    import axiosClient from '@/axiosClient'

    export default {
    data() {
        const letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('')
        return {
            letter: this.$route.params.letter,
            beers: [],
            letters,
        }
    },
    created() {
        axiosClient.get(`beers?beer_name=${this.letter}`).then(response => {
            this.beers = response.data
            console.log(this.beers)
        })
    },
    computed: {
        filteredBeers: function () {
            return this.beers.filter(beer => {
                return beer.name.startsWith(`${this.letter}`)
            })
        },
    },
    }
    </script>
```

[Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZqlV.png)

I tried to add startrsWith() but it's still shows all element that contains letter not start with that letter. Maybe i have to use some function? I donn't know. Please for any help

Also what can i do that it will refresh automatically after i click on letter?

Comment: Does your console.log after the API call show the right results ?

Comment: In your `v-for`, you need to use your `filteredBeers` computed, not the `beers` array. `v-for="beer in filteredBeers"`

Comment: Thank you! And how can i make this refresh automatically after i click on letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `v-for`, you iterate `beers`, not `filteredBeers`

Comment: Thank you! And how can i make this refresh automatically after i click on letter?